# Issue with Spatie Laravel Multitenancy: Table 'laravel.users' doesn't exist (Still using the landlord instead of tenant)

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm encountering an issue while implementing Spatie Laravel Multitenancy in my Laravel application. When attempting to run the application, I'm getting the following error:

```sql
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.users' doesn't exist
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

Here's my setup:

Database Configuration:
I have separate databases for tenants and landlord. The tenant database connection is configured as follows:

```php
'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => null,
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'landlord' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Multitenancy Configuration:
In my config/multitenancy.php file, I have the following configuration:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent;
use Illuminate\Events\CallQueuedListener;
use Illuminate\Mail\SendQueuedMailable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\SendQueuedNotifications;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\ForgetCurrentTenantAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MakeQueueTenantAwareAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MakeTenantCurrentAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Actions\MigrateTenantAction;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Models\Tenant;
use Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantDatabaseTask;

return [
    /*
     * This class is responsible for determining which tenant should be current
     * for the given request.
     *
     * This class should extend `Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\TenantFinder`
     *
     */
    'tenant_finder' => Spatie\Multitenancy\TenantFinder\DomainTenantFinder::class,

    /*
     * These fields are used by tenant:artisan command to match one or more tenant
     */
    'tenant_artisan_search_fields' => [
        'id',
    ],

    /*
     * These tasks will be performed when switching tenants.
     *
     * A valid task is any class that implements Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchTenantTask
     */
    'switch_tenant_tasks' => [
        // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\PrefixCacheTask::class,
        SwitchTenantDatabaseTask::class,
        // \Spatie\Multitenancy\Tasks\SwitchRouteCacheTask::class,
    ],

    /*
     * This class is the model used for storing configuration on tenants.
     *
     * It must be or extend `Spatie\Multitenancy\Models\Tenant::class`
     */
    'tenant_model' => Tenant::class,

    /*
     * If there is a current tenant when dispatching a job, the id of the current tenant
     * will be automatically set on the job. When the job is executed, the set
     * tenant on the job will be made current.
     */
    'queues_are_tenant_aware_by_default' => true,

    /*
     * The connection name to reach the tenant database.
     *
     * Set to `null` to use the default connection.
     */
    'tenant_database_connection_name' => 'tenant',

    /*
     * The connection name to reach the landlord database
     */
    'landlord_database_connection_name' =>null,

    /*
     * This key will be used to bind the current tenant in the container.
     */
    'current_tenant_container_key' => 'currentTenant',

    /**
     * Set it to `true` if you like to cache the tenant(s) routes
     * in a shared file using the `SwitchRouteCacheTask`.
     */
    'shared_routes_cache' => false,

    /*
     * You can customize some of the behavior of this package by using our own custom action.
     * Your custom action should always extend the default one.
     */
    'actions' => [
        'make_tenant_current_action' => MakeTenantCurrentAction::class,
        'forget_current_tenant_action' => ForgetCurrentTenantAction::class,
        'make_queue_tenant_aware_action' => MakeQueueTenantAwareAction::class,
        'migrate_tenant' => MigrateTenantAction::class,
    ],

    /*
     * You can customize the way in which the package resolves the queuable to a job.
     *
     * For example, using the package laravel-actions (by Loris Leiva), you can
     * resolve JobDecorator to getAction() like so: JobDecorator::class => 'getAction'
     */
    'queueable_to_job' => [
        SendQueuedMailable::class => 'mailable',
        SendQueuedNotifications::class => 'notification',
        CallQueuedListener::class => 'class',
        BroadcastEvent::class => 'event',
    ],

    /*
     * Jobs tenant aware even if these don't implement the TenantAware interface.
     */
    'tenant_aware_jobs' => [
        // ...
    ],

    /*
     * Jobs not tenant aware even if these don't implement the NotTenantAware interface.
     */
    'not_tenant_aware_jobs' => [
        // ...
    ],
];
```

Database Environment Variables:
In my .env file, I have configured the database connection for the landlord:

```
DB_CONNECTION=landlord
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Error Context:
The error is occurring when the application tries to access the users table. However, in a multitenant architecture, each tenant should have its own users table. It seems like the application is trying to access the users table in the landlord database instead of the tenant database.

Question:

How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the application accesses the correct users table based on the current tenant when using Spatie Laravel Multitenancy?

I implemented Spatie Laravel Multitenancy in my Laravel application following the documentation and configured separate databases for tenants and the landlord. I expected the application to correctly access the database tables based on the current tenant. Specifically, when accessing the users table, I expected the application to use the users table associated with the current tenant's database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after few hours of tests the answer is to make the tenant conection as default connection `DB_CONNECTION=tenant`